# State Parameter in Authorization Request (OAuth2)

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I have read some documentations online about preventing CSRF attacks on OAuth2 requests using the state parameter. However, my understanding is that the state parameter, although random and unguessable, is still part of the request URL, and can easily be copied by an attacker, who can then intercept the server response, alter some information, and then put back the state value that was read from the initial request. When the client validates the response, the state value would still match! Could you tell what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only protection against interception and alteration of the request and/or response, which is a specific type of man-in-the-middle attack, is to use secure transmission between the client and the server.

Traditionally, this is done by using https: rather than http: as the protocol.